# Only a few internet pages will load

Tags: internet

Okay, I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my hp 2140. For some reason it will only display some webpages (google and reddit work). It will download and install updates and applications fine, but doesn't display most pages... Can anyone help?

Comment: Please give me an example of a website that does NOT work, and I will send you instructions to check whether it is a DNS problem.

Comment: 1. did you check using another browser?  if you install proxy adon's or if you configure your browser using proxy check that to. 2. if you can not access yahoo.com try pinging yahoo, if pinging works try browsing. if you can't browse, let us know what kind of connection you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change MTU in Network Manager. It works for me 2 years ago.